# IntelliJ IDEA rendering bad font

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, intellij-idea, jvm, antialiasing

I set a new font in IDE UI Settings and Font & Color option.

Here:
[image]

and here:
[image]

After restart IDEA, good font in UI and bad in Workspace:
[image]

Have any idea how to change this?

Comment: If you are on Linux, [check this thread](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233) for the workarounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [open issue logged](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233) with some useful suggestions from the community.

There is an [easy approach](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233#comment=27-363762) that can improve results a bit and a [really complicated one](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233#comment=27-472038) involving patched JDK/system libraries versions, but with the best possible results.