# How to anti-alias fix in Idea IDE even jvaa DWMA flags not working

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, antialiasing

i am using idea IDE with Elementary OS Luna.I tried flag kind of "DWMA" but those are not working still UI is not getting anti-aliased but mine friend with Ubuntu is getting anti-aliasing properly can somebody tell me whats going on i am using oracle JDK 7..

Comment: [Here you go](http://superuser.com/a/623596/268507).

Comment: Above method is not working here is the [screenshot](http://s12.postimg.org/s1jgvdmpp/Screenshot_from_2014_03_09_16_16_50.png)

Comment: Ok. I have the similar issue and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19697698/2650174) be helpful for me.